# Miss data when using response = urllib2.urlopen(url) python

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, urlopen

I am using urllib2 in python to get response from website. But response return miss some data. When I using file_get_contents in php, it return full data. This is code I using:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print response.read()
```

Comment: Perhaps you will find using the requests library more intuitive to use than urllib2.

Comment: do you know any library is good to get response

Comment: http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/